# Determining where string equality comparison fails

Tags: c, c-strings

Given these strings

```
char * foo = "The Name of the Game";

char * boo = "The Name of the Rose"
```

I want to determine the address of the first mismatched character, in order to extract the  common header ("*The Name of the* ").

I know the hand-coded loop is trivial, but I'm curious if there's any variant of `strcmp()` or other library function that will do this automatically for me? And is the answer any different in C++?

Comment: Nope, I don't think any such ["standard" `string.h` function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/string) exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Nope.  No such standard [`string.h`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/string) function exists.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this simple function will do what you want, using `strncmp`.
*(lightly tested...)*

```
int find_mismatch(const char* foo, const char* boo) 
{
    int n = 0;
    while (!strncmp(foo,boo,n)) { ++n; }
    return n-1;
}

int main(void)
{
    char * foo = "The Name of the Game";
    char * boo = "The Name of the Rose";
    int n = find_mismatch(foo,bar);

    printf("The strings differ at position %d (%c vs. %c)\n", n, foo[n], boo[n]);
}
```

**Output**
`The string differ at position 16 (G vs. R)`

Comment: Ouch. Well, that *uses* strncmp, but not in a good way. Performance on  long strings will be terrible!

Comment: If you want to work on better performance, you could also do a binary search for the place where the strings differ.  That code would be a bit more complex.

Comment: The problem is that strcpy has ready has O(n) performance, so find_mismatch basically has O(n^2). Replacing the `while` line with `while (*foo++ != *bar++) ++n;` is all that's needed.

Comment: That would be faster, yes. But it does not use a `strXXX` function as you originally requested.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you could use strspn(str1, str2) which returns the length of the initial portion of str1 that consists only of parts of str2.

```
char *foo = "The Name of the Game";
char *boo = "The Name of the Rose";
size_t len = strspn(foo, boo);

printf("The strings differ after %u characters", (unsigned int)len);
```

Comment: The example on this page (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strspn/) makes clear that it does not work the way you think it does.